# required file not seen on heroku in jekyll blog

Tags: ruby, heroku, jekyll

This is my dir structure

```
.
├── _layouts
│   └── default.html
├── _posts
├── _site
│   ├── config.ru
│   ├── devart.rb
│   └── index.html
├── config.ru
├── devart.rb
└── index.html
```

My config.ru

```
require 'devart.rb'
run Sinatra::Application
```

When I push this to heroku in the log files I see this error saying `devart` file is not found during the require. What the heck am I doing wrong??

```
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- devart (LoadError)
```

Comment: Maybe this can give you an idea:
http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/142273

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby 1.9.2 no longer has current dir in loadpath. So changed to

```
require './devart.rb'
```

to get it to work.

Comment: Or use `require_relative 'devart.rb'`